# Dax - Filter by value then count occurence in table

Tags: filter, powerbi, dax, measure

I am working with an employee table and was wondering if I could get some help.

My data table has rows with start and end date values.  I filter these rows down using `Filter(data table, [start date]<=[Measure.MaxMonth]&&[end date]>=[Measure.MaxMonth]`.  `[Measure.MaxMonth]` is a measure that sits on a disconnected date table and functions like a parameter.

Here is a formula that I have been testing but have not been getting the desired results:

`Measure.DirectReports = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(Data Table),filter(Data Table,Data Table[Mgr ID]=Data Table[Emp ID]&&Data Table[Start Date]<=[Meas.LastMonth]&&Data Table[End Date]>=[Meas.LastMonth]))`

Measure.LastMonth = max(EOM[End of Month]) ->this value can equal any month end between July 2005 and July 2017.  EOM is a date table with a row for each month end - 7/31/2005, 8/31/2005,....7/31/2017

This gives me a table structured liked this:

```
Emp ID,Emp Attr,Mgr ID,Start Date,End Date
1,B,4,10/1/2013,10/6/2013
1,B,4,10/7/2013,12/29/2013
1,B,4,12/30/2013,12/28/2014
1,B,8,12/29/2014,10/4/2015
1,B,8,10/5/2015,12/27/2015
1,B,12,12/28/2015,5/15/2016
1,B,12,5/16/2016,10/2/2016
1,B,12,10/3/2016,12/25/2016
2,B,4,12/1/2014,12/28/2014
2,B,4,12/29/2014,12/27/2015
2,B,4,12/28/2015,2/7/2016
2,B,4,2/8/2016,3/6/2016
2,B,8,3/7/2016,6/1/2016
3,B,6,7/1/2015,12/27/2015
3,B,8,12/28/2015,6/30/2016
3,B,6,7/1/2016,9/4/2016
3,B,6,9/5/2016,12/25/2016
3,B,6,12/26/2016,5/7/2017
3,B,4,5/8/2017,6/11/2017
3,B,4,6/12/2017,6/25/2017
3,B,4,6/26/2017,7/9/2017
3,B,19,7/10/2017,12/31/9999
4,A,,7/1/1996,4/2/2006
4,A,,4/3/2006,12/31/2007
4,A,,1/1/2008,5/22/2011
4,A,,5/23/2011,11/16/2014
4,A,,11/17/2014,6/11/2017
4,A,,6/12/2017,6/25/2017
4,A,,6/26/2017,12/31/9999
5,B,4,11/8/2010,1/2/2011
5,B,4,1/3/2011,5/22/2011
5,B,4,5/23/2011,1/1/2012
5,B,4,1/2/2012,5/31/2012
5,B,4,6/1/2012,7/1/2012
5,B,4,7/2/2012,9/7/2012
6,B,4,1/3/2011,5/22/2011
6,B,4,5/23/2011,9/5/2011
6,B,4,9/6/2011,1/1/2012
6,B,4,1/2/2012,12/30/2012
6,B,4,12/31/2012,12/29/2013
6,B,4,12/30/2013,5/18/2014
6,B,4,5/19/2014,11/16/2014
6,B,4,11/17/2014,12/28/2014
6,B,4,12/29/2014,3/22/2015
6,B,4,3/23/2015,12/27/2015
6,B,4,12/28/2015,3/6/2016
6,B,4,3/7/2016,8/21/2016
6,B,4,8/22/2016,10/30/2016
6,B,4,10/31/2016,12/25/2016
6,B,4,12/26/2016,1/8/2017
6,B,4,1/9/2017,5/7/2017
6,B,4,5/8/2017,6/11/2017
6,B,4,6/12/2017,6/25/2017
6,B,4,6/26/2017,12/31/9999
7,B,4,1/2/2012,12/30/2012
7,B,4,12/31/2012,12/29/2013
7,B,4,12/30/2013,5/18/2014
7,B,4,5/19/2014,11/16/2014
7,B,4,11/17/2014,12/28/2014
7,B,4,12/29/2014,3/8/2015
7,B,4,3/9/2015,1/18/2016
7,B,4,1/19/2016,2/19/2016
8,B,6,12/31/2012,11/3/2013
8,B,4,11/4/2013,12/29/2013
8,B,4,12/30/2013,1/26/2014
8,B,4,1/27/2014,5/18/2014
8,B,4,5/19/2014,11/16/2014
8,B,4,11/17/2014,12/28/2014
8,B,4,12/29/2014,3/22/2015
8,B,4,3/23/2015,12/27/2015
8,B,4,12/28/2015,7/1/2016
10,B,4,10/3/2011,12/18/2011
10,B,4,12/19/2011,12/30/2012
10,B,4,12/31/2012,2/23/2013
10,B,4,2/24/2013,11/20/2014
11,B,4,2/1/2011,2/27/2011
11,B,4,2/28/2011,5/1/2011
12,B,4,9/15/2012,12/31/2012
12,B,4,9/15/2012,12/31/2012
12,B,4,1/1/2013,12/31/2013
12,B,4,1/1/2013,4/30/2014
12,B,4,1/1/2014,4/30/2014
12,B,4,5/1/2014,11/16/2014
12,B,4,5/1/2014,12/28/2014
12,B,4,11/17/2014,11/30/2014
12,B,4,12/1/2014,12/28/2014
12,B,4,12/29/2014,12/27/2015
12,B,4,12/29/2014,12/30/2016
12,B,4,12/28/2015,12/30/2016
12,B,4,12/31/2016,12/31/2016
12,B,4,1/1/2017,6/11/2017
12,B,4,6/12/2017,6/25/2017
12,B,4,6/26/2017,7/9/2017
12,B,19,7/10/2017,12/31/9999
13,B,4,12/28/2015,9/4/2016
13,B,4,9/5/2016,12/25/2016
13,B,4,12/26/2016,6/11/2017
13,B,4,6/12/2017,6/25/2017
13,B,4,6/26/2017,12/31/9999
14,B,4,1/12/2015,12/27/2015
14,B,4,12/28/2015,12/25/2016
14,B,4,12/26/2016,6/11/2017
14,B,4,6/12/2017,6/25/2017
14,B,4,6/26/2017,12/31/9999
16,B,4,9/14/2015,10/19/2015
17,B,6,8/22/2016,12/25/2016
17,B,6,12/26/2016,5/7/2017
17,B,4,5/8/2017,6/11/2017
17,B,4,6/12/2017,6/25/2017
17,B,4,6/26/2017,7/9/2017
17,B,19,7/10/2017,12/31/9999
18,B,6,9/12/2016,12/25/2016
18,B,6,12/26/2016,5/7/2017
18,B,13,5/8/2017,6/11/2017
18,B,13,6/12/2017,6/25/2017
18,B,13,6/26/2017,7/9/2017
18,B,19,7/10/2017,12/31/9999
19,B,4,7/10/2017,12/31/9999
```

Empl ID is a unique employee number.  Mgr ID references the Empl ID of the employee's manager at the desired point in time (Measure.LastMonth).  Emp Attr is an attribute of the employee, such as level.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to create a measure that will count the occurrences of `Empl` `ID` in `Mgr` `ID`?  Ideally, if I am creating a visual in Power BI and I filter based on `Empl Attr ="A"`, can the resulting measure value give me the `result = 3` -> the empl id "1" occurs 3 times in the mgr id column.

I need this to be a measure and not a calculated column so that I can trend the results over time (end of month on X axis in trend visual).

Thanks for the help and let me know if you have any questions!

Answer (score 0):

**Edit** - Updating basically the entire answer due to new information about the problem.

I feel that your core problem is trying to create a relationship between two tables based on the evaluation of an expression (End of Month between Start Date and End Date). From my experience, the easiest way to workaround this is to `CROSSJOIN` the two tables and then filter it down based on whatever expression you would like. For this, I created a new table with this formula.

```
Results = DISTINCT(
    SELECTCOLUMNS(
        FILTER(
            CROSSJOIN('Data Table', EOM),
            'Data Table'[Start Date] <= EOM[End of Month] && 'Data Table'[End Date] >= EOM[End of Month]
        ),
        "Emp ID", [Emp ID],
        "End of Month", [End of Month]
    )
)
```

[image: Crossjoin]

One more piece before finally making the relationships, we need a list of unique employee IDs. That can easily be obtained by creating a new table with this formula.

```
Employees = DISTINCT(
    SELECTCOLUMNS('Data Table',
        "Emp ID", 'Data Table'[Emp ID]
    )
)
```

[image: Employees]

From here, create relationships between all of the tables as shown in the image below.

[image: Relationships]

I know you asked for a measure, but bear with me as I feel confident that this will get you what you want. Add a new column to the Results table with this formula.

```
DirectReports = CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS('Data Table'),
    FILTER(ALL('Data Table'),
        'Data Table'[Mgr ID] = EARLIER(Results[Emp ID]) &&
        'Data Table'[Start Date] <= EARLIER(Results[End of Month]) &&
        'Data Table'[End Date] >= EARLIER(Results[End of Month])
    )
)
```

[image: Count Column]

At this point, I would hide the Emp ID and End of Month from the results table and any other field(s) you desire. From there, make your visuals. For example, you said you wanted to show direct report count over time, so I made this simple line chart and card.

[image: Results]

Comment: Thanks for the response Joe.  I was wondering if I could make this a measure instead of a calculated column.  I would like to trend the mgr id count over time (Meas.MaxMonth) on X-axis. For each possible value of Meas.MaxMonth, I would like to filter my data table and calculate new counts.  Let me know if more info would help.  I really appreciate it!

Comment: Emp ID,Emp Attr,Mgr ID,Start Date,End Date
2,B,4,12/1/2014,12/28/2014
2,B,4,12/29/2014,12/27/2015
2,B,4,12/28/2015,2/7/2016
2,B,4,2/8/2016,3/6/2016
2,B,8,3/7/2016,6/1/2016
3,B,6,7/1/2015,12/27/2015
3,B,8,12/28/2015,6/30/2016
3,B,6,7/1/2016,9/4/2016
3,B,6,9/5/2016,12/25/2016
3,B,6,12/26/2016,5/7/2017
3,B,4,5/8/2017,6/11/2017
3,B,4,6/12/2017,6/25/2017
3,B,4,6/26/2017,7/9/2017
3,B,19,7/10/2017,12/31/9999
4,A,,7/1/1996,4/2/2006
4,A,,4/3/2006,12/31/2007
4,A,,1/1/2008,5/22/2011
4,A,,5/23/2011,11/16/2014
4,A,,11/17/2014,6/11/2017
4,A,,6/12/2017,6/25/2017
4,A,,6/26/2017,12/31/9999

Comment: @user3620704 - What do you mean "for each possible value of Meas.MaxMonth"? In your question, you say it is a measure; can you update your question with the code that calculates it? It might also help to update your question with more complete sample data as well (as opposed to the comments).

Comment: Sorry about the confusion Joe.  I just updated the original post.  I really appreciate the help!